# NULL-related error running Dynamic Query in Windows CLI environment where MySQL is installed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a batch file (mysql.bat) based on Windows.

The phrase at the bottom is A dynamic query statement for outputting only the values of fields in the mysql.user table that include '_priv' as "*_priv" in the field.

The query is as follows, and it works when you run it inside SQL.

And it works if you create a shell script in the CLI in a Unix environment, receive the ID, PWD, and run the syntax.

However, in a Windows environment, the syntax fails.

```
mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "SET @pattern = '_priv'; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO @columns FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'mysql' AND table_name = 'user' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', @pattern, '%'); SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT HOST, USER, ', @columns, ' FROM mysql.user'); PREPARE dynamic_query FROM @query; EXECUTE dynamic_query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_query;" -t
```

The Batch File code is as follows.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p id=Please Write ID :
set /p pwd=Please Write PWD :

echo ID: %id%
echo PWD : !pwd!


mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "SET @pattern = '_priv'; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO @columns FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'mysql' AND table_name = 'user' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', @pattern, '%'); SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT HOST, USER, ', @columns, ' FROM mysql.user'); PREPARE dynamic_query FROM @query; EXECUTE dynamic_query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_query;" -t
```

The syntax for the error is as follows.

```
PREPARE dynamic_query FROM @query;
```

I tried to run the above dynamic syntax in the CLI in Windows environment by cutting it based on ;.

As expected, errors occur from the PREPARE statement.

It works well until the previous sentence.

The error seems to be an error related to NULL.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

Is this an error because Windows MySQL and Unix/Linux MySQL deal with NULL values differently?

I would appreciate it if you could explain the cause and how to solve it.

I made a batch script and cut it as below.

Again, errors occur in the same place.

The same error occurs in the "PREPARE" statement in the Windows CLI environment.

It works fine inside SQL and with Unix Shell Script.

```
mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "SET @pattern ='_priv';" -t
mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO @columns FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'mysql' AND table_name = 'user' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', @pattern, '%');" -t
mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT HOST, USER, ', @columns, ' FROM mysql.user');" -t
mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "PREPARE dynamic_query FROM @query;" -t
mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "EXECUTE dynamic_query;" -t
mysql -u %id% -p"!pwd!" -e "DEALLOCATE PREPARE daynamic_query;" -t >> %COMPUTERNAME%-result.txt
```

Comment: :facepalm: `%', @pattern, '%` in your batch code is treated as environ variable name. Double `%%` chars. *It works fine inside SQL and with Unix Shell Script.* .. and in CMD window but not in .BAT file.

Comment: As well as changing that to `%%', @pattern, '%%`, if you are using a file named `mysql` and naming your batch file `mysql`, you are asking for trouble. One of the ways you can counteract that is to change every line containing the string `mysql` to `mysql.exe`, or even better, use its full path, e.g. `"%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe"`.

Comment: @Akina Thanks to your reply, the problem has been solved.

When I ran the query, I didn't recognize that this would be a problem because there was no error in the '%' part.

I don't think I recognized the difference between Windows(%), Unix/Linux($).

Thank you very much..!